# Angular 2 thinking and way

Tags: typescript, angular2

Ситуация: 
Есть два очень похожих компонента: превью статьи на главной странице, и сама статья, при переходе на "читать дальше". У компонента превью свой сервис, который тянет данные через http. В роутере, при переходе на полноую статью (другой компонент) указан компонент статьи, непосредственно.

Вопрос: 
Создавать копмоненту свой собственный сервис, который будет дублировать код сервиса превьюхи, либо же использовать один компонент, просто с отдельным шаблоном целой статьи (//не нашел, как юзать несколько шаблонов в одном компоненте), либо же ваш вариант. Интересует именно правильный подход с точки зрения angular way и TS.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: можешь сделать им общий сервис

Comment: @Grundy, об этом я не подумал, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для обоих компонентов можно сделать через один сервис